# Probability of sum of sequences of integers

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution, combinatorics, sum

Let **K** be a positive integer.Suppose that the integers **1,2,3,...,3k+1**are written down in random order.What is the probability that at no time during this process, the sum of the integers that have been written up to that time is a positive integer divisible by 3? Your answer should be in closed form, but may include factorials.

**Solution**:-$\frac{k!(k+1)!}{(2k)!(3k+1)}$

Because divisibility by three
is all that matters, we work modulo three. Evidently the positions of the zeros do not
change any of the divisibility properties. We ask, then, for the equivalent probability that
a random sequence of k zeros, k+1 ones, and k twos has no zero partial sums (modulo 3).

A sequence satisfying the conditions cannot begin with a zero. This leaves (2k+1)/(3k+1)
of the sequences to consider, but for them, the positions of the zeros do not matter. If a
partial sum is ever 1, the next value in the sequence cannot be 2, and if a partial sum is
ever 2, the next value cannot be 1. A straightforward induction shows the only possible
sequence (ignoring the zeros) is 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, …, 1, 2. There are (k+1)!k! such sequences
out of all (2k+1)! sequences and they are equally probable. Multiplying by (2k+1)/(3k+1) produces the answer.
This answer is taken from

[Putnam Soluions 2007-Haverford College]

Comment: Hint: you don't need to work with all $3k+1$ integers; you only need to work with their values modulo $3.$ For that purpose it might be most convenient to interpret these values as a multiset consisting of $k$ zeros (corresponding to $3,6,\ldots, 3k$), $k+1$ ones (corresponding to $1,4,\ldots, 3k+1$), and $k$ values of $-1$ (corresponding to $2,5,\ldots, 3k-1$). The rules of addition are that $1+1=-1$ and $-1+-1=1.$ The question requires that no partial sum equal zero. Note that the zeros can appear anywhere after the start of the sequence, reducing the problem to counting patterns of $\pm1.$

Comment: BTW, this was Putnam problem 2007 A3.  Google "putnam divisible by 3 random" if you would like a detailed solution.